# Unable to get the string i want?

Tags: c#

I am making a WinForm C# application. I have a button which will search for a string and give the value next to it. Here is my code:

```
WebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(Settings.Default.FoodList);
WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());

string foods = sr.ReadToEnd();
string item = TXTSearchItem.Text;

try
{
    var startIndex = foods.IndexOf(item + "-", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    var dashIndex = foods.IndexOf("-", startIndex);
    var endIndex = foods.IndexOf("\r\n", startIndex);
    var foodName = foods.Substring(startIndex, dashIndex - startIndex);
    var footCount = foods.Substring(dashIndex + 1, endIndex - dashIndex - 1);
    MessageBox.Show($"Item {foodName} is worth {footCount} SmartPoints.", "Item search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, info);
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item was not found.", "Item search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, warning);
}
```

For some reason it will not get the last string. Here is what the string contains:

```
   goldfish-4
   eggs-0
   banana-0
   chicken-0
   apple-0
   grapes-0
```

If I type in `grapes`, it will say the item was not found. But if i have a MessageBox showing the foods string, it will show it correctly. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `endIndex = foods.IndexOf("\r\n", startIndex);` will be `-1` as the *last* line does not end with `\r\n`.  Consider splitting the text on `\r\n` then looping, this will also avoid issues like `bc-1` matching `abc-1`

Comment: have you debugged it? What line jumps to exception?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it is easier to use `string.Split()` here?
Could be done in that way:

```
string item = TXTSearchItem.Text;
string foods = sr.ReadToEnd(); // Maybe you already have ReadLines method here
var lines = foods.Split(new []{ Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var expectedLine = lines.FirstOrDefault($"{item}-"); // assume that you have fixed format here
if (expectedLine != null)
{
   var splittedLine = expectedLine.Split('-');
   var foodName = splittedLine.First();
   var foodCount = splittedLine.Last();
   MessageBox.Show($"Item {foodName} is worth {footCount} SmartPoints.", "Item search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, info);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Item was not found.", "Item search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, warning);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot split on Environment.NewLine because it could not convert string to char

Comment: My bad - wrote it from the head. You can check the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

A string is not a good place to store those information. If the price of those item is unique( no banana=1 and banana=2). You should store it in a datastructure that reflect this unicity and will ease your search for price.

Like a [`Dictionary<string,int>`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)<sup>1</sup>.

```
var input = @"   goldfish-4
eggs-0
banana-0
chicken-0
apple-0
grapes-0";

string pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)-(?<value>\d+)";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

var r = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .ToDictionary(
                m => m.Groups["key"].Value,
                m => int.Parse(m.Groups["value"].Value)
            );
```

:RegexExplain:

Then accessing the data is easy. even adding a new product or changing a price . And if you ever need to store it again in a file please use some serialisation.

---

<sup>1: If price is an int.</sup>